# apk building through jenkins getting crash on real device

Tags: android, gradle, jenkins, crash, apk

I am facing issue with my apk buildt through jenkins - its getting crash on using it on real android TV device.
Since my build creation jenkins job is getting success  but when i am using that apk on my real devices its getting failed and error logs says :
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_773e439/Offline;`
I want to know is this something related to jenkins job or some code level changes need to be done by devolpers.

Attaching error logs below getting through android studio when launching app and getting crash:

2023-08-17 16:29:16.608 29114-29114/tv.airtel.xstream.tvapp.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: tv.airtel.xstream.tvapp.debug, PID: 29114
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_773e439/Offline;
at com.airtel.vision.AtvSdk.$jacocoInit(Unknown Source:13)
at com.airtel.vision.AtvSdk.(Unknown Source:0)
at tv.airtel.xstream.config.di.AppModuleKt$appModule$1$2.invoke(AppModule.kt:20)
at tv.airtel.xstream.config.di.AppModuleKt$appModule$1$2.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
at org.kodein.di.bindings.Singleton$getFactory$1$1$1.invoke(standardBindings.kt:134)
at org.kodein.di.bindings.SingletonReference.make(references.kt:34)
at org.kodein.di.bindings.Singleton$getFactory$1$1.invoke(standardBindings.kt:134)
at org.kodein.di.bindings.Singleton$getFactory$1$1.invoke(standardBindings.kt:99)
at org.kodein.di.bindings.MultiItemScopeRegistry.getOrCreate(scopes.kt:62)
at org.kodein.di.bindings.Singleton$getFactory$1.invoke(standardBindings.kt:134)
at org.kodein.di.bindings.Singleton$getFactory$1.invoke(standardBindings.kt:99)
at org.kodein.di.KodeinContainer$provider$$inlined$toProvider$1.invoke(curry.kt:14)
at org.kodein.di.KodeinAwareKt$Instance$1.invoke(KodeinAware.kt:152)
at org.kodein.di.KodeinProperty$provideDelegate$1.invoke(properties.kt:39)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
at tv.airtel.xstream.PlayApplication.getAtvSdk(Unknown Source:7)
at tv.airtel.xstream.PlayApplication.initAtv(PlayApplication.kt:56)
at tv.airtel.xstream.PlayApplication.onCreate(PlayApplication.kt:48)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5882)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_773e439.Offline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/tv.airtel.xstream.tvapp.debug--k_aipq4ftZEc1641nrz7w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/tv.airtel.xstream.tvapp.debug--k_aipq4ftZEc1641nrz7w==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /product/lib]]

Comment: Please add full of error and log of jenkins.

Comment: @AmirhosseinTaheri just provided the logs when app got crashed while using it on real device. No exception on jenkins

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.